# Dealing with improper integrals for double integration using Monte Carlo method

Tags: numerical-methods, monte-carlo

I am trying to use Monte Carlo method to solve problems regarding double integrals. In particular, the integral to be solved is in the form of
$$
\int_{b}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{\infty} f(t|x)g(x) dx dt.
$$

Here, $f(t|x)$ is the conditional probability where
$$f(t|x)=e^{\beta x}\lambda e^{-e^{\beta x}\lambda t}, g(x)=\mu e^{-\mu x}.$$

I am aware the existence of alternatives numerical procedure such as cubature and quadrature. However, I'm prone to use Monte Carlo method as it is easier for coding implementation.
To deal with the improper integrals, change of variable is needed.

Let $x=a+\frac{u}{1-u}$ and $t=b+\frac{v}{1-v}$, then the integrands are updated as
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f\bigg(b+\frac{v}{1-v}\bigg|a+\frac{u}{1-u}\bigg)g\bigg(a+\frac{u}{1-u}\bigg) \times \frac{1}{(1-u)^2(1-v)^2} dudv.
$$

Next, we can use the standard procedure of Monte Carlo method which is to generate $u$ and $v$ from uniform distribution and approximate the integration above as
$$
I\approx (1-0)(1-0) \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{f\big(b+\frac{v_{i}}{1-v_{i}}\big|a+\frac{u_{i}}{1-u_{i}}\big)g\big(a+\frac{u_{i}}{1-u_{i}}\big)}{(1-u_{i})^2(1-v_{i})^2}}{N}
$$
Can I know whether this method is valid?

Since the $t$ is dependent on $x$ and I'm not sure whether we can simply do the change of variable as above or not.

Comment: How is $t$ dependent on $x$? You don't describe this at all. And how do you define the iterated integral $\int_b^\infty\int_a^\infty \dots dx dt$ if $t$ depends on $x$? Particularly as $x$ is only a dummy variable of the inner integral, and thus there is no $x$ around for the $t$ of the outer integral to depend upon! Also, what is the notation $f(t|x)$ supposed to mean? This is not some standard notation of general functions that you can expect people to just understand.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, question is updated to answer your first question. But I don't quite get what your second question is.